# Get attributes from the rel attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, rel

Im using a plugin that requires the rel-element to look like this.

```
<ul id="product-thumbs-list">
      <li><a href="1-big.jpg" rel="useZoom: 'cdonZoom', smallImage: '1.jpg'"></li>
      <li><a href="2-big.jpg" rel="useZoom: 'cdonZoom', smallImage: '2.jpg'"></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to get the smallImage-value via jQuery?
In this case, '1.jpg, or '2.jpg'.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way with jQuery. You might just have to get the contents of rel using `.attr('rel')` and split it into an array then find the result that starts with smallImage and get the filename from that.

Comment: It's a pretty poor plugin to be storing data like that in the rel attribute. Should be using the data-xxx="" or at least storing the data as JSON at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
$("#product-thumbs-list a").each(function(index) {
   var arrTemp = $(this).attr("rel").split("smallImage: ");
   var value = arrTemp[1];
   alert(value);
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/4FGzY/).

Comment: This works great, as long as you donsn't input anything after the smallImage value. Well, at least i won't. Thx

Comment: @Maartin that's very true.. to support such scenario you can add another `split` like this: `var value = arrTemp[1].split(", ")[0];` assuming the format is consistent. jsFiddle example for this case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/4FGzY/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can get the rel attributes that returns the string "useZoom: 'cdonZoom', smallImage: '1.jpg'".
Than you can split the string using ":" and get the last array item.

I hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Superbly ugly, but you *can* use the dreaded `eval()`, provided that the `rel` data are "well-formed":

```
$(function() {
    $('a').mouseover(function() {
        eval('var rel = {' + $(this).attr('rel') + '};');
        $('#out').text(rel.smallImage);
    });
});
```

With HTML:

```
<ul id="product-thumbs-list">
    <li><a href="1-big.jpg" rel="useZoom: 'cdonZoom', smallImage: '1.jpg'">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2-big.jpg" rel="useZoom: 'cdonZoom', smallImage: '2.jpg'">link2</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="out"></p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/LSC36/1/).